# Python capture all printed output

Tags: python, piping

I am looking to write console based programs in python that can execute functions to perform generic tasks, pretty generic. Is it possible to capture everything written to the console by print calls in a function without needing to return a string, similar to how bash and the windows shell allow piping the output of a program to a text file, ie

ipconfig>ipconfig.txt

but doing this inside of a python program, where a function is called, everything that was printed to the console inside of that function is gathered as a list of strings, and then can be saved to a txt file of the users choice?

Comment: Sure. Run the Python script from the shell, and use the shell to redirect output as usual.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by setting `sys.stdout` to be a file of your choice

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('out.dat', 'w')
print "Hello"

sys.stdout.close()
```

Will not display any output but will create a file called `out.dat` with the printed text.

Note that this doesn't need to be an actual file but could be a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instance, which you can just use the `getvalue` method of to access everything that has been printed previously.

Comment: @Simon Gibbons , Is it also possible to also output the same on the console along with parallely writing in the "out.dat" file?