# How to write multiple paragraphs from console to a file - Python

Tags: python

I have a line of code which prints a paragraph like this :

```
print("An Apple a day keeps the doctor away ... ") #paragraph1
.
.
.
print("Two Apples a day keeps two doctors away ... ") #paragraph2
.
.
.
json.dump(someData) #paragraph3
```

I just want to direct all the paragraphs that have been printed in the console onto a file.

Note:

- 1) I do not want to use .write() method every single time below the
  print statement.
- 2) I want to output to the file using the script    itself and not
  the console. (Not something like this
  [How to redirect console output to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682087/how-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-text-file)
  )

Is there any function that can achieve this? (Write all the paragraphs printed in the console onto a file in one shot?)

Comment: `print` also takes a `file` argument.

Comment: @Nabin kindly read the point no. 2 in 'Note' .

Comment: Do you want to write it to a JSON file?

Comment: @Oqhax not json file exactly as of now. Just a .txt will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Redirect output of a Function into a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885878/python-redirect-output-of-a-function-into-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divert the stdout to a file

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing your paragraphs into string variables. It would look like this

```
p1 = "An Apple a day keeps the doctor away ... "
p2 = "Two Apples a day keeps two doctor away ... "

print(p1)
print(p2)

with open("output.txt", "w")as output:
    p1and2 = p1 + p2
    output.write(p1and2)
```

Hope this works